# extern struct forward declaration

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I am trying to compile some old code that include a mix of C and C++. I found following syntax:

```
extern struct Edge;
typedef struct Edge
{
    ...
    Edge* edges;
    ...
} Edge;
```

When I try to compile with GCC I get an error:

`a storage class can only be specified for objects and functions
    extern struct Edge;`

After I remove extern it compiles. I might be mistaken, but it does look to me like a forward declaration of Edge, but why there an `extern` keyword at the front of `struct`?

Comment: `struct Edge* edges;` - code then compiles as C, but with warnings.

Comment: The `extern struct Edge;` line is the start of an external declaration, but it contains no 'declarators' — no names of actual objects.  It is therefore pointless, as the message indicates.  Deleting it is safe; it was never necessary (or even beneficial) that I know of, and is certainly not now either necessary or beneficial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, `extern struct S;` is valid but not useful: it means exactly the same thing as `struct S;` In `extern struct S a, b, c, ...;`, `extern` applies to `a`, `b`, `c`, ... regardless of how many variables are declared, even if zero variables are declared.

In C++, `extern struct S;` is invalid. For compatibility with C, most C++ compilers allow it as an extension, but GCC doesn't. You were right to just remove the `extern` keyword.

It's possible that code originally written `extern struct S s;` was split up into separate declarations for `struct S` and `s`, and `extern` was accidentally left in. Since the compiler didn't mind, the author didn't notice.

Answer (score 0):

I installed and tested other most popular compilers. Aforementioned code:

- does NOT compile with GCC-7.3.0 and produces following `error`:

`main.cpp:1:1: error: a storage class can only be specified for objects and functions
 extern struct Edge;
 ^~~~~~`

- compiles using `clang-6.0` and produces following `warning`:

`main.cpp:1:1: warning: 'extern' is not permitted on a declaration of a type
      [-Wmissing-declarations]
extern struct Edge;`

- compiles using `Visual Studio 2017` and produces following `warning`:

`warning C4091: 'extern ': ignored on left of 'Edge' when no variable is declared`